# I am trying the code by JAVA - Selenium for the WebApplication

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Can anyone select any item from the drop down list box of "Furniture Type". I got the clicking on the the furniture type by

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//select)[1]")).click();
```

But I am unable to select any one text from the drop down list box. By Select class I tried, But I couldn't get the solution.

The url is " http://bangalore.quikr.com/post-classifieds-ads/?postadcategoryid=218 "

The exception I am getting is "no such element exception".

Answer (score 0):

Usually you should first check the path using developer tools or similar browser extension, or record using Selenium IDE. In this case for instance, I don't see any `select` element on that page: Furniture Type is an `input` with `type=text` and the selectable options are `input` with `type=radio`. Also `(//select)[1]` is not a valid xpath.

So you can find it by

```
WebElement typeBox = driver.findElement(By.id("Furniture_Type_searchBox"));
```

Since Furniture Type is an `input` with `type=text`, you can then focus on it like this:

```
typeBox.sendKeys("");
```

That should also open a drop-down, from which you should select a radio button like this (selecting 'Bed Set' for example):

```
WebElement radio = driver.findElement(
    By.xpath("//div[@class='attr-container']//input[@lblval='Bed Set']"));
```

And you click to select it

```
radio.click();
```

Comment: please give me your mail id,The group has blocked me for 3 days from posting the questions